# How to change file associations in Inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need the user to be able to double click on a .pdb file and have it open with myPgm.exe.

What is the syntax to associate a file type (myData.pdb) with an executable (myPgm.exe)?

Is it a registry entry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File association in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536030/file-association-in-inno-setup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A File association is a series of Registry entries.  For more info, take a look at [How to Use File Associations Microsoft Sample](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/122787/).

If you don't want to create system-wide file associations, you can create [specific user file associations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4585078/255257) too.

To create registry entries from your script, read the [ISS Documentation: Registry Section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection).  If you find any problems come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 15):

There's [an entry for that in the FAQ](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc) on the Inno Setup web site. Here is the quote of the relevant section of the FAQ:

#### Creating File Associations

First set the `[Setup]` section directive `ChangesAssociations` to `yes`. Then create `[Registry]` entries as shown below.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".myp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "MyProgramFile"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

`".myp"` is the extension we're associating. `"MyProgramFile"` is the internal name for the file type as stored in the registry. Make sure you use a unique name for this so you don't inadvertently overwrite another application's registry key.

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgramFile"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "My Program File"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

`"My Program File"` above is the name for the file type as shown in Explorer.

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgramFile\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\MYPROG.EXE,0"
```

`"DefaultIcon"` is the registry key that specifies the filename containing the icon to associate with the file type. `",0"` tells Explorer to use the first icon from `MYPROG.EXE`. (`",1"` would mean the second icon.)

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgramFile\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\MYPROG.EXE"" ""%1"""
```

`"shell\open\command"` is the registry key that specifies the program to execute when a file of the type is double-clicked in Explorer. The surrounding quotes are in the command line so it handles long filenames correctly.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. As instead of linking to other pages, it explains clearly what steps should have been taken to register a file extension.

Answer (score 1):

that works well for me.
just rename MYEXTENSION

```
[Registry]
Root: HKA ; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.MYEXTENSION"; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""
Root: HKA ; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppName}"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";  Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""
Root: HKA ; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppName}\DefaultIcon"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"; ValueType: string;  ValueName:""
Root: HKA ; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppName}\shell\open\command"; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1""";  ValueType: string; ValueName: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MyAppAssocExt ".mp3"
```

and

```
[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocExt}\OpenWithProgids"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueData: ""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppAssocName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1"""
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\Applications\{#MyAppExeName}\SupportedTypes"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".myp"; ValueData: ""

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\도깨비 플레이어"; Filename: "{app}\XMPlayer.exe"
Name: "{userdesktop}\도깨비 플레이어"; Filename: "{app}\XMPlayer.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\XMPlayer.exe";
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Goblin Player}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).