# Who should be responsible for performing file associations?

Tags: .net

I'm currently performing file association when the program starts. This however requires elevated access and since I'm associating scripting files I feel like I'm doing something wrong that could compromise the security of the user. What is the correct way to do file association? Through a setup? Through the program? If the latter, how can I prevent malicious scripts to be executed through the program?

Comment: I guess you should ask the user first with a UI (like most programs do when they install) and then ask for elevation. In the program itself, you could also have a menu that is capable of redoing it when the user feels it's needed.

Comment: Maybe this could be worth looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705188/programmatically-add-file-association-without-admin-rights-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can register per-user associations which does not require elevation. System-wide associations are usually registered in installer.

Comment: I think all your answers are reasonable but I think I will accept @AlexeyIvanov 's  answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register per-user associations which does not require elevation.
System-wide associations are usually registered in installer.

System-wide associations are stored in `HKLM\Software\Classes`.
Per-user associations are stored in `HKCU\Software\Classes`.

The former is writable by Administrators only, the latter is usually writable by users¹.

The contents of these keys is merged into `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

---

¹ This is how, to some extent, Default Programs work: when you change your defaults, only per-user associations are changed so that different users can use different apps to open files.

For more information, see [File Types and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Default Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx).